# Remove commas from json_encode

Tags: php, sql, json, csv

So, I want to remove the commas from between results.
The reason I want to do this is because later in the process I export to CSV and the commas are making my tables go crazy.

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="lunes">Lunes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="martes">Martes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="miercoles">Miércoles<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="jueves">Jueves<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="viernes">Viernes<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="sabado">Sábado<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="piden[]" value="domingo">Domingo<br>
```

Here is my PHP

```
$piden =json_encode($_POST['piden']);
```

And my results on the Database looks like this.
The only problem are the commas in between results.

```
["miercoles","sabado","domingo"]
```

I could not find any similar questions.

Comment: Why do you need to remove commas? Why do you need json then? Why you don't use `str_replace`?

Comment: the purpose of json_encode is to make a JSON object.  Since your object is an array, it is a comma delimited json valid list.  You can always do other things, instead of encoding, like `str_replace`, etc

Comment: I am really really new at this. 
Could you give an example using str_replace?

Comment: @LuisRodriguez, can you change your CSV separator? I like to use \t (tab) as field separator, exactly to avoid problems with commas in my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove commas then why are you using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

After comma removal the strings cannot be decoded anymore. Use a different encoding, for example, join the values using a separator:

```
$piden = implode('/', $_POST['piden']);
```

However, even this way you may have issues when the input data contains commas. Most probably you are "encoding" the CSV by hand and fail to properly quote the values that contain the separator (commas f.e).

The PHP function [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) can do all the hard work for you when it comes to export data as CSV.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you all. 
And sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @luis-rodriguez if its work for u than accept this answer by click on the left tick